# Error Execute "osk" AKA On-Screen Keyboard VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Iam trying to execute on-screen keyboard form vb.net.

i have try this code :

```
shell("notepad") 'this is working
shell("cmd") 'this is working to
shell("dxdiag") 'this is working to
```

but when iam trying to execute "osk" AKA On-Screen Keyboard its show error

```
shell("osk") '
```

The Error :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: File not found.

i think to execute "osk" i need special condition or what?
and i have trying to import System.IO but still cant be done..

pls help..thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Process.Start` instead for shell to open applications since it is more featured than `shell`

```
Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\OSK.EXE")
```